# Objects distort if near the canvas sides - three.js

Tags: camera, three.js, distortion

I have a three.js scene with spheres, but when I zoom in a sphere and I move with orbit controls so it is in the side of the canvas (on in the center and deep in) it looses its round shape (do not care about the lines) :

[image]

What can I do ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There will always be some distortion, but it is worse with a large camera field-of-view (fov).

A reasonable value for `camera.fov` is 40-45 degrees. A smaller value would produce less distortion.

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( fov, aspect, near, far );
```

And for reference, `camera.fov` is the field-of-view in the *vertical* direction.

three.js r.70

Comment: if you could tell me what is the equation to find the z-offset for the camera when I change the fov from 75 to 15 degrees so that my camera will be in the same position I would be gratefull.

Comment: Sorry, you will have to make a new post if you have another question.

Comment: that's right : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28290562/equation-to-position-camera-in-fov-change-three-js

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour of a THREE.**Perspective**Camera. Try it yourself with a digital camera at home.

The only real way to fix it is to use an THREE.**Orthographic**Camera, but this likely has other issues you do not want to have, such as objects not becoming smaller when they are further away.

Comment: you mean THREE.OrthographicCamera